# Using object with functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, object

Hey guys am new to javascript development. i have been confused with the objects which i used in javascript..I have took a look to facebook javascript sdk and found out this code.

```
FB.getlogin(function(response)) {


  "data": [

{

  "name": "XXX", 

  "id": "YYY"

},

{

  "name": "ZZZ", 

  "id": "OOO"

},
```

}

In `fb-js-sdk` the obect properties can be accessed by `console.log(response.data[0].name )`.This seems natural.

But when i tried the actual code in js(not fb sdk)

```
function some() {

return 5 }


some.anotherfunction(function() {

{

 "name" : "randomname"

"age" : 12

}
```

when i tried to acess the object like `anotherfunction.name` it shows error.I know am doing something wrong in my code .It would be really helpful if you help me in finding error and for fixing it ..Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
function some() {   
    return 5
}


some.anotherfunction = function() {
    return 'From another function';
}
```

You can then call `anotherFunction` the way you want -

```
some.anotherfunction();
```

You can even accept parameters. Functions in JavaScript are objects, and you can give them properties.

---

**Update**

```
some.anotherfunction = function() {
    return {
        'name' : 'My Name',
        'age' : 20
    };
}
```

You can then use this -

```
var obj = some.anotherfunction();

// Access name 
console.log(obj.name);
```

Comment: the thing which i need is that i want to return objects from the function somefunction ..

Answer (score 0):

I think that your function doesn't return anything. Try using return in your object:

```
some.anotherfunction(function() {

     return {

      "name" : "randomname"

      "age" : 12

      }
    )
```

Comment: the question is how can i return name ??..can it be done like anotherfunction.name; ?